# Find the highest frequency letter in a text

Tags: r

I have to find the letter that occurs the most within a text in a table layout.

I was given this to help me but I'm not sure how to use it.

```
letter.count <- function(text, letters) {
## count the number of times letters appears in the text
return(sum(unlist(strsplit(text, "")) %in% letters))
}
```

The data is a set of tweets and I have to find the sample mean frequency.
The table of data is set out so that the tweet is on one side and negative is on the other side. I've managed to isolate the negative tweets of all the tweets and now I just need to find the most common letter of all the tweets.

Comment: Is this a homework question? Do you understand what the `letter.count` function does?

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this, with `table`

```
locate.letters <- function(text, letters){
    x <- unlist(strsplit(text, ''))
    tt <- table(x[x %in% letters])
    list(table = tt, sum = sum(tt), max = tt[which.max(tt)])
}

> txt
## [1] "I am a geography student. I am interested in mining tweets for 
## geographic data in support of my thesis on the new Geography. I know maps
## are being developed by some developers. I would like to be able to 
## develop maps myself. How do I do that? What is the process? 
## Thanks in advance."

> locate.letters(txt, letters[1:10])
## $table

##  a  b  c  d  e  f  g  h  i 
## 17  4  3 11 30  3  7  9 11 

## $sum
## [1] 95

## $max
##  e 
## 30
```